# I'm a novice at Powershell and im trying to complete a task

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-server

I'm starting to work with Powershell and I've been doing some courses online. At this moment I'm stuck in a Challenge, I hope some good soul can help me with the instructions from the course.

Instructions are:

1-Find out what Windows features are installed on the server machine. (I'm remoting command to a computer named "Server")

2-Select only the data stored in the Name and InstallState columns.

3-Sort the data by the Name property in ascending (alphabetical) order.

4-Make sure the output format is set to table

5-Save the final output into a file called C:\features.txt on your desktop machine.

What I have come up with is this:

```
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server -ScriptBlock{
>> Get-WindowsFeature | Select-Object -Property Name, InstallState | Sort-Object -Property Name | Format-Table
>> } | Out-File C:\features.txt
```

I have tried both with and without the select-object command since I know the format-table command works almost the same in this case. Thank u!

Comment: What is your question/problem?  You've given some requirements and an attempt at a solution, but don't say what specifically you need help with.  Does the code not do what you want?  if not, what's it not doing (e.g. gives an error, doesn't return any data, wrong format, etc)

Comment: thank you, I'm just wondering if the command is enough for all those instruction or if it is need to add or remove something

Comment: How would **we** know what **you** are expecting the output to be?  When you ran that exact same command, did it not give you what you're after?

Comment: You have steps you are after, then execute them that way one step at a time, ensure you are getting the results you'd expect, and then put it all together.

Do this on one computer, your own, then refactor it to use on multiple ones.

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per my comment for example.

```
# 1-Find out what Windows features are installed on the server machine. 
Get-WindowsFeature
# Results
<#

#>


# 2-Select only the data stored in the Name and InstallState columns.
Get-WindowsFeature | 
Select-Object -Property Name, InstallState
# Results
<#

#>

# 3 - Sort the data by the Name property in ascending (alphabetical) order.
Get-WindowsFeature | 
Select-Object -Property Name, InstallState | 
Sort-Object -Property Name
# Results
<#

#>

# 4-Make sure the output format is set to table
Get-WindowsFeature | 
Select-Object -Property Name, InstallState | 
Sort-Object -Property Name | 
Format-Table # though this is not needed, since table is the default for less than 5 properties.
# Results
<#

#>

<#
# 5-Save the final output into a file called C:\features.txt on your desktop 
machine.
#>
Get-WindowsFeature | 
Select-Object -Property Name, InstallState | 
Sort-Object -Property Name | 
Export-Csv -Path 'SomePathName' -NoTypeInformation -Append


# (I'm remoting command to a computer named "Server")
$Computers | 
ForEach-Object {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PSItem.ComputerName -ScriptBlock{
        Get-WindowsFeature | 
        Select-Object -Property Name, InstallState | 
        Sort-Object -Property Name | 
        Export-Csv -Path 'SomePathName' -NoTypeInformation  -Append
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When ever I invoke a scriptblock on a remote computer i assign it to a variable and then handle the results this:

```
$myResults= Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server -ScriptBlock{…}
Foreach ($item in $myResults){
   Write-host” $item.name / 
   $item.nstallState”
}
```

You use the pipeline rather excessively which is not wrong but for me personally still a beginner my self it is not easy to totally comprehend what each of them is exactly returning and forwarding to the next. Dont try to write a perfect line with several pips in the first attempt. Start with the smallest fastest fraction of the task. In this case yust get them all out without filter and pipelines. Then work your way from there, make little changes, use write-host to display the results and trail and error yourself to a deeper understanding of each of them. And then in the end u can chain them up.

Answer (score 0):

```
invoke-command -computername server -scriptblock {Get-WindowsFeature | ? installstate -eq installed | select-object name,installstate | sort-object name | format-table} | out-file c:\features.txt
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on how the proposed solution solves the problem and how it helps the OP.